# Can child content be added to MarkupString with RenderFragment?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have code like this;

```
@((MarkupString)$"<{item.Tagname}> {ChildContent} </{item.TagName}>")
```

ChildContent in the middle is a RenderFragment object, but it outputs as follows;

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment"

Is there a way to make it work normally this way?

Comment: I can't repro this problem.  Also, be _extremely_ cautious when using `MarkupString`.  For example, if `item.TagName` contains a value provided by users, you could open yourself up to XSS attacks.  (Or `ChildContent`, for that matter)

Comment: Post a complete  [mre].

Comment: Oh I don't know that. Thanks for the advice. I will look into other methods @KirkWoll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do something like this.

The example uses a `RenderTreeBuilder` to construct the markup.  It's the eqivalent to writing assembler for components, but as the markup gets complex it's the only sensible way!

If you use this method one word of advice: the sequence numbers need to be coded manually, do not use an iterator.

```
@this.content

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string TagName { get; set; } = "div";

    private RenderFragment content => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, TagName);
        builder.AddContent(1, ChildContent);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

Or as a complete component:

```
public class ComponentClass : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string TagName { get; set; } = "div";

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, TagName);
        builder.AddContent(1, ChildContent);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It's absolutely worked